# Mysql add 1 day to timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, unix-timestamp

I've  field in my db named "eventstart". The value in there is a unix timestamp. I want to add 1 day to this, but it only stores 0.

I tried:

```
UPDATE mytable SET eventstart=TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,1,eventstart) WHERE 1

UPDATE mytable SET eventstart=TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,1,DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(eventstart), '%d-%m-%Y')) WHERE 1

UPDATE mytable SET eventstart=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMPADD(DAY,1,DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(eventstart), '%d-%m-%Y'))) WHERE 1
```

...and things like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the eventstart stores a unix_timestamp (you must have defined it when you created the table) this means it the values should be in seconds. A day is 86400 seconds; so you should add this to the values in eventstart field. Consequently the update would be

```
UPDATE myTable SET eventstart = (eventstart + 86400)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: this adds nothing, field stays unchanged. Defined is the field as 
eventstart int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,

Answer (score 5):

Can you try with this:

```
UPDATE mytable SET eventstart = eventstart + interval 1 day WHERE 1
```

Answer (score 4):

use this command:

```
UPDATE myTable SET eventstart = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(eventstart), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```